# Page Transitions effects dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, css-transitions

I am using the the following css library http://tympanus.net/Development/PageTransitions/.

I want to use it with different URL not in single page (i.e www.example.com/pageone , www.example.com/pagetwo) may be angularjs  Ng-view animations can do, but i don't know how to do. can any one help ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to animate, fade and so on when reloading. 
You can load the same html content on eache url address and then make som transition magic as it is in example. 
By the way; Tympanus is the best site with inspirations :). Especially Mary Lou.

Comment: actuality i want to do something like this http://clientdemowork.com/yoursquare/html/ click on login button then click on logo when u got second page but my client want this with different URL and title

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page
Here is very good solution for you. Basicly it's ajax.